# What is the best practice in creating space using margins with CSS?

Tags: css

Every now and then I need to space out between elements, e.g. between header and a box. All examples I see add margin-top property to box or margin-bottom to header. But these take affect everywhere. If I wanted it to have page specific margins etc. What is the best practice? Should I just use style elements in html or should I create rules like these in CSS and use classes?

```
.margin-top-10px { margin-top: 10px }
.margin-top-15px { margin-top: 10px }
...
```

Is this a good practice? Is it too much clutter in CSS?

Comment: Avoid inline CSS whenever possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't do that. You'll end up with an unmaintainable mess.

If you have, for example, a header on a specific page that needs more room than usual, give it it's own class:

```
.lonelyheader {
  margin-bottom: 10pt;
}
```

remember you can combine multiple classes, so you can still share styles with other headers:

```
.heading {   
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3pt;
}
```

and then:

```
<div class="heading lonelyheader">etc.</div>
```

Comment: But then wouldn't all these one-off classes clutter the CSS file?

Comment: No. If you need to style the headers differently in different places, why would specific classes for each cause any more clutter than any of the other ways they'd need to be styled? Those styles need a home, regardless. Given that home a descriptive name isn't going to make things *worse. 

Take a look at [OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) and [SMACSS](http://smacss.com/) for better thoughts than mine on scalable, maintainable CSS.